# Why a input value is not picked up by a function

Tags: r, string, function, ggplot2, tidyverse

I was wondering why my `rstatix::get_test_label()` call throws in an error saying: `stat.test should be an object of class: t_test, ..., anova_test, ...`?

The first argument (`stat.test`) is actually an `anova_test` as the input value. Is there a fix to this?

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/memory.csv")[-1]
stacked_DVs <- pivot_longer(d, c(MP,SE), names_to = "DV") 
grouped <- stacked_DVs %>% group_by(DV)

res.aov <- anova_test(value ~ Group, data = grouped)

rstatix::get_test_label(stat.test = res.aov, detailed = TRUE) # using `anova_test` as input

#Error in stop_ifnot_class(stat.test, .class = names(allowed.tests)) : 
#  stat.test should be an object of class: t_test, wilcox_test, . . .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue would be that the `res.aov` is returning the output as a `tibble` class whereas the `get_test_label` expects class to be `anova_test`, `rstatix_test`.  We could do a `group_split` into a `list`, apply the `anova_test` individually in the `list` elements, and then use `get_test_label` so that the attributes are not lost

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
stacked_DVs %>% 
   group_split(DV) %>% 
   map(~ .x %>%
             anova_test(value ~ Group) %>% 
             rstatix::get_test_label(detailed = TRUE))
#[[1]]
#paste("Anova, ", italic("F"), "(2,49)", " = ", "32.12, ", italic("p"), 
#    " = ", "<0.0001", paste(", ", eta["g"]^2, " = ", 0.57), "")

#[[2]]
#paste("Anova, ", italic("F"), "(2,49)", " = ", "32.67, ", italic("p"), 
#    " = ", "<0.0001", paste(", ", eta["g"]^2, " = ", 0.57), "")
```

---

Or another option is to do a `nest_by`

```
out <- stacked_DVs %>%
          nest_by(DV) %>%
          mutate(test = list(anova_test(value ~ Group, data = data)),
                label = list(get_test_label(test, detailed = TRUE)))

 out
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Rowwise:  DV
#  DV                  data test             label     
#  <chr> <list<tbl_df[,2]>> <list>           <list>    
#1 MP              [52 × 2] <anova_test[,7]> <language>
#2 SE              [52 × 2] <anova_test[,7]> <language>


out$label
#[[1]]
#paste("Anova, ", italic("F"), "(2,49)", " = ", "32.12, ", italic("p"), 
#    " = ", "<0.0001", paste(", ", eta["g"]^2, " = ", 0.57), "")

#[[2]]
#paste("Anova, ", italic("F"), "(2,49)", " = ", "32.67, ", italic("p"), 
#    " = ", "<0.0001", paste(", ", eta["g"]^2, " = ", 0.57), "")
```

---

Checking the `class` of OP's object

```
class(res.aov)
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

class(out$test[[1]])
#[1] "anova_test"   "data.frame"   "rstatix_test"
class(out$test[[2]])
#[1] "anova_test"   "data.frame"   "rstatix_test"
```

If we do this on a ungrouped data, the `class` attributes would be `anova_test`, `rstatix_test`

```
stacked_DVs %>% 
     anova_test(value ~ Group) %>% 
     class
#[1] "anova_test"   "data.frame"   "rstatix_test"
```

---

It is related to the way `anova_test` handles `grouped_df`.  Here is the snippet in source code where it does an `if/else`

```
anova_test
...
...

  if (is_grouped_df(data)) {
        results <- data %>% doo(~.anova_test(data = ., .args = .args, 
            effect.size = effect.size, error = error, observed = observed, 
            detailed = detailed), result = "anova")
        if ("anova" %in% colnames(results)) {
            results <- results %>% mutate(anova = map(.data$anova, 
                .append_anova_class))
        }
    }
    else {
        results <- .anova_test(data, .args = .args, effect.size = effect.size, 
            error = error, observed = observed, detailed = detailed) %>% 
            .append_anova_class()
    }
```

---

So, if we wanted to use `doo`, then place the output in a `list`

```
stacked_DVs %>%
    group_by(DV) %>% 
    doo(~list(anova_test(value ~ Group, data = .))) %>%
    mutate(label = map(`.results.`, ~ get_test_label(.x[[1]], detailed = TRUE))) %>%
    pull(label)
#[[1]]
#paste("Anova, ", italic("F"), "(2,49)", " = ", "32.12, ", italic("p"), 
#    " = ", "<0.0001", paste(", ", eta["g"]^2, " = ", 0.57), "")

#[[2]]
#paste("Anova, ", italic("F"), "(2,49)", " = ", "32.67, ", italic("p"), 
#    " = ", "<0.0001", paste(", ", eta["g"]^2, " = ", 0.57), "")
```

Comment: @rnorouzian can you check the updated answer.  Sorry, somehow I thought that you are using the same grouping earlier

Comment: @rnorouzian it seems to be deleted

Comment: Sorry yes, all I needed was to use `::` :) Thank you!